# Export or convert files [ovf - mf - vmdk] to img

Tags: vmware, qemu, vps, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

An exported VM of which I have 3 files.

- os.mf
- os.ovf
- os-disk1.vmdk

I want to convert this to a * .img image

Answer (score 0):

For Images Qemu-img can do these and many other conversions. The openstack project has a nice summary [here](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html).

On the other hand `.ovf' and '.mf' are metadata files which are not converted by that, instead you can look at` virt-convert` [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/virt-convert.1.html) but since options are not 100% equivalent that conversion might be lossy/imperfect or needs manual tuning. BTW since ovf references the image files it will also try to convert those for you (by using qemu-img).

Comment: The idea is to download a compressed file VMware with mikortik and its crack (ovf - mf - vmdk], conver them to img, to be able to use a script and upload them to a vps, installing mikrotik on ubuntu vps